# How to convert a datepicker to ISO format in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a question. If I have a datepicker that returns me data like this:

[image]

How can I convert this result into a date of type ISO? so that it can be stored in MongoDB.

This is the code of the html part.

```
 <form class="row row-cols-sm-auto" [formGroup]="dateForm" (submit)="Date()">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xlg-3">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" readonly formControlName="date"
                 name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
              Date
          </button>
      </div>
 </form>
```

This is the typescript part:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {

   this.dateForm = this.fb.group({
     date: ['', Validators.required]
   })
   
  }

  Date(){
   
    const { date } = this.dateForm.value
    console.log(date)
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `toISOString` function to convert your date into `ISO` format. Also try changing `const` keyword into date type.    `Date.toISOString()`

Answer (score 0):

According to ng-bootstrap's [official docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#date-model) you should configure an `NgbDateAdapte` service and provide it:

The docs provide a [good example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#adapter) on how to do it

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomDateParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {

  readonly DELIMITER = '/';

  parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct | null {
    if (value) {
      const date = value.split(this.DELIMITER);
      return {
        day : parseInt(date[0], 10),
        month : parseInt(date[1], 10),
        year : parseInt(date[2], 10)
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  format(date: NgbDateStruct | null): string {
    return date ? date.day + this.DELIMITER + date.month + this.DELIMITER + date.year : '';
  }
}
```

(don't forget to provide it in your root app)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `toISOString()` to your destructured object property named `date` above:

Examples as as on [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString):

```js
const event = new Date('05 October 2011 14:48 UTC');
console.log(event.toString());
// expected output: Wed Oct 05 2011 16:48:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
// (note: your timezone may vary)

console.log(event.toISOString());
// expected output: 2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z
```